# Get Output of A Function in Python In a variable

Tags: python, eel

My python script downloads youtube videos using the youtube-dl library. It only prints progress and does not return progress value. I have to pump the progress to my HTML page. Using return() only gives code as 0 or none. JavaScript is configured to get return value and add it to a textarea. It is not possible to configure the library as it is huge.

```
stream.download(quiet=False, filepath=outfilepath)
```

This calls a module pafy which further calls youtube-dl.

```
 16,498,967.0 Bytes [100.00%] received. Rate: [5446 KB/s].  ETA: [0 secs]
```

This output does not go to HTML but is printed in python shell.
How to get this output in my HTML page?

Comment: Did you try overloading the print function to store your results?

Comment: Can you please explain? I do not know overloading print function.

Comment: Since print normally uses stdout, this may be helpful for modifying print behavior  [Redirecting stdout](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/06/16/python-101-redirecting-stdout/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is overriding the builtin `sys.stdout.write` method which is being used by `pafy` to print to console. You can make it also log the print statements into a data structure.

In the following code, I used a list to store all strings passed to `sys.stdout.write` function. This will log all your download progress prints into this list. You can always access your latest log from the list.

```
import pafy
import sys

#List for logging required printed strings
myPrintLogs=[]

def write(text):
    """Overloaded sys.stdout.write function"""
    myPrintLogs.append(text) #Adding text into Logs List
    if len(text) == 0:
        return
    old_sys_write(text + '\n') #Calling the actual method for printing text

old_sys_write=sys.stdout.write 
sys.stdout.write=write
```

Add your download code after initializing this. You'll have all the console output in the list `myPrintLogs`. You should call the method for download in a new thread so that you can monitor the logs in main thread.

Comment: @Hamza-Kurshid ```Error - return ("Latest Progress: ",myPrintLogs[-1])
IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: @BhavyaGupta Make sure you define the method before everything else. And then access the list myPrintLogs after you are sure the required print statements have been executed.

Comment: Yes, I did it the exact way. Still it is blank. the print command is not given in my script. It is originating from some imported module.

Comment: The module `pafy` doesn't use `print` in its implementation. It uses `sys.stdout.write` instead. So I updated the code to override this method instead. You can try this one!

Comment: You are great! It works like charm. But now, I am having SSL Error from python. Can you help me in that too?

Comment: Please share complete stack trace.